# Updating issue with JIRA rest api 4.4

Tags: jira

I am trying to update the fixVersion of an issue via the JIRA rest api. The JIRA version is 4.4.3#663-r165197. It is the instance hosted by codehaus, not sure if that makes a difference or not.

The request looks like:

```
  curl -u [username]:[password] -X PUT -H 'Content-type: application/json' \
    -d  "http://jira.codehaus.org/rest/api/latest/issue/GEOS-[id]"
```

```
{
   "update":{
      "fixVersions":[
         {
            "set":[
               {
                  "name":"2.2-beta3"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

But I get back a 405, method not allowed error. Which makes sense if I look at the rest api docs for that version [1]. They seem to indicate there is no way to update an issue in this manner. BUt if I look at the docs for the latest version [2] they seem to indicate it is possible.

So I guess the question is how do I update an issue in this manner in JIRA 4.4? Or is it not possible?

Thanks!

[1] https://developer.atlassian.com/static/rest/jira/4.4.1.html#id151460

[2] http://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#id165544

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 4.4 you have to use the SOAP updateIssue method. 5.0 fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

```
Prepare Json data as below(Here java as technology i had used), and pass using put method/API.

public static String generateJson(String customFieldId, Object value,
        String attribute) {

    if (isBlankOrNull(attribute)) {
        return "\"" + customFieldId + "\":" + "\"" + value + "\"";
    } else {
        return "\"" + customFieldId + "\":{\"" + attribute + "\":\"" + ""
                + value + "\"}";
    }
}



    public static int invokePutMethod(String auth, String url, String data) {

            int statusCode = 0;
            try {
                Client client = Client.create();
                WebResource webResource = client.resource(url);
                ClientResponse response = webResource
                        .header("Authorization", "Basic " + auth)
                        .type("application/json").accept("application/json")
                        .put(ClientResponse.class, data);
                statusCode = response.getStatus();
                return statusCode;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Constants.ERROR.info(Level.INFO, e);
                // vjErrorLog.info(Level.INFO, e);
            }
            return statusCode;
        }

attribute could be key, id, name, value etc,

In case of fix version or components, you may have one more way to prepare json data

    return "\"" + customFieldId + "\":[{\"set\" :[{ \"" + attribute
                        + "\" :" + "\"" + data + "\"}]}]";

and invoke put method with above json data.
```